# Need to Transpose some SQL values over 2 indices grouped by unmatching dates (SQL and Python)

Tags: python, sql, pivot

I included an image that shows what I am trying to do in SQL.  The table you see  on the left is what I get from running a SQL query on my server.  I am trying to create the table on the right using SQL/ Python.  I would use a pivot, but as a pivot aggregates the values, I would have to take an average, sum, min, max, or something else of the component number column.  Effectively, I need a 2 indices transpose.  There can be multiple tests done for each serial number.  I need to make the first test by date show up in the first test values column, same for the second, third, or fourth test.  I need the values for each serial number and each component to show up in "test 1", "test 2", "test 3".  The tricky part is that test 1, test 2, and test 3 are different for each part and yet they still need to be grouped by into the buckets by sequential test date for each serial number.

If anyone could help me out with some methods or help me generate some pseudocode for what I am trying to do, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks.

Here is the link to the image of the tables:
The left is what my SQL query pulls, and the right is how I want it to be.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` and conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    serial_number,
    component_number
    max(case when rn = 1 then test_value end) test1,
    max(case when rn = 2 then test_value end) test2
from (
    select
        t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by serial_number, component_number order by test_date) rn
    from mytable t
) t
group by serial_number, component_number
```

In the subquery, `row_number()` assigns a rank to each record within groups sharing the same `serial_number` and `component_number`. Then, the outer query aggregates by `serial_number` and `component_number`, and spreads the `test_value`s accross columns according to their rank. You can expand the `select` clause of the outer query with more conditional `max()`s to handle more than two tests per `(serial_number, component_number)` tuple.

Comment: Thanks! I will work on implementing this and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply. I can confirm your solution worked.  Thanks, I greatly appreciated the help!